# Secure Rest Apis Using Okta + Oauth

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, okta

currently am Creating Rest Apis in Spring Boot I want to secure Those Apis Using Okta Wit Oauth.

Can Any one Help On this....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Okta's Spring Boot Starter for this. https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot

Warning: there is an issue where you can't use devtools with this starter.

Comment: while calling Rest Apis i need to Use access Token How to I generate That Access Token. I already look in to Okta Developer site i found some steps to generate Access Token. How to call Token url and what input i need to pass while calling

Comment: See https://developer.okta.com/standards/OAuth/#oauth-20-and-okta. You might be able to use our Auth JS library to get the token, or our Angular and React SDKs: https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js.